# Why I cannot call ajax call from Angular

Tags: ajax, angular

I have this component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserServices} from '../services/UserServices';

@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    template: '<h1>HOLA</h1>'
})

export class UsersComponent {
    users: Object;

    constructor(userServices: UserServices) {
        userServices.getUsersList();
    }
}
```

And In the UserServices I have this code:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'

export class UserServices {
    users: Array<any>;
    http: any;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    getUsersList() {
        this.http.get('./users.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
    }

}
```

I want to call an ajax call for the `users` custom tag.
But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot resolve all parameters for UserServices(?). Make sure they all
>   have valid type or annotations.

When I remove the HTTP parameters, import and call, it has no error, so I guess the problem is there, but I cannot find out the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing couple of relevant sections in DI.

There are multiple ways to inject using `provide` and `@inject` or using `@Injectable` decorators. Here you, for instance, decorate your service with `@Injectable` i.e

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

// You do not need to do this, but creating an interface for more strong typing. You could as well create a User class here and use that as view model.
interface IUser{
  name:string;
}

@Injectable()
class UserServices {
    users: Array<IUser>;

    constructor(private http:Http) {}

    getUsersList():Observable<Array<IUser>> {
       return this.http.get('./users.json')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

}

export {IUser, UserServices};
```

Inject `UserServices` and `HTTP_PROVIDERS` at the root, Generally you inject the services that you need as singleton across your app at the app root level. If not, you can inject the service alone in the UserComponent decorator's `providers` array.

i.e

```
bootstrap(UsersComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, UserServices])
```

or within the component's decorator:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    template: `<h1>Users</h1>
    <div *ngFor="#user of users">
    {{user.name}}
    </div>

    `,
    providers:[UserServices] 
})
```

Consume this in your component and subscribe <sup>**1**</sup> to the returned observable.

```
export class UsersComponent {
    users: Array<IUser>;

    constructor(userServices: UserServices) {
        userServices.getUsersList().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
    }
}
```

<sub><sup>**1**</sup>You can also use [`async pipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#the-stateful-asyncpipe-) (application of this depends upon the use case) and set the value of `this.users` as the observable instead of subscribing them explicitly.</sub>

```
<div *ngFor="#user of users | async">
  {{user.name}}
</div>
```

<sub>and</sub>

```
this.users = userServices.getUsersList();
```

*Note: In the example i just imported `map operator` in order to get the map as a part of observable returned by http (`import rxjs/add/operator/map`) since this is not mapped in the system Js config `paths` property at a global level.*

Here is a working **[plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KZ77kk?p=preview)**.

Comment: Perfect!! Thankss a lot!

Comment: @PSL I have a question not regarding the subject if you don't mind. What the heck is `<>` you use multiple times? I mean why you use `Array<IUser>` and not `IUser[]`? How is it called, and where I can learn more about it?

Comment: @Eggy sure, it is part of generics syntax to specify the sub type of a generic type like Observable, Array, promise etc or any other custom types as well. But to you point in case if array you could use the literal syntax as well i.e []. More about generics here http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The service needs an `Injectable()` annotation

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class UsersComponent {
```

for DI to be able to inject `Http` or other dependencies to its constructor.

Comment: You're missing the `@` :P

Comment: yes yes. It will sound strange, but after adding that lines I'm getting `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` o.O

Comment: I don't have a solution for this. Seems unrelated.

Comment: what's the content of `users.json`?, make sure it's all `json` correct syntax, no `js` comments or anything else.

Comment: When I add the http: Http to the constructor, I have the issue

Comment: Apparently Http is not inside angular2/http, Where should it be?

Comment: I'm a bit of a loss here, because I don't use TS myself. In the doc examples they use `import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';`. Maybe some configuration is not correct. See for example https://github.com/angular/angular.io/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=http